# Surprising PartialFunction literal

Tags: scala

I just got puzzled by the fact that this partial function `pf` doesn't blow up with a `MatchError` when inner is not `InnerA`

```scala
sealed trait Inner
case class InnerA(name: String) extends Inner
case class InnerB(name: String, value: Int) extends Inner
case class Input(id: String, inner: Inner)

case class Output(id: String, inner: InnerA)

  val pf: PartialFunction[Input, Output] = { input =>
    input.inner match {
      case innerA: InnerA =>
        val Input(id, _) = input
        Output(id, innerA)
    }
  }
```

instead it is simply undefined so this passes

```scala
    Seq(
      Input("1", InnerA("a1")),
      Input("2", InnerB("b2", 2)),
      Input("3", InnerA("a3"))
    ).collect(pf) shouldBe Seq(
      Output("1", InnerA("a1")),
      Output("3", InnerA("a3"))
    )
```

If I add a line I get a compilation warning and trying to pass an InnerB in the collect above throws a `MatchError` (as I originally expected):

```scala
  val pf: PartialFunction[Input, Output] = { input =>
    println(input)
    input.inner match {
      case innerA: InnerA =>
        val Input(id, _) = input
        Output(id, innerA)
    }
  }
```

```
InnerB(b2,2) (of class casa.InnerB)
scala.MatchError: InnerB(b2,2) (of class casa.InnerB)
```

Why is this? Is this quirk documented somewhere?

(I'm using Scala 2.13.3)

Comment: The idea of a partial function, is well, being partial, meaning it doesn't match everything. Not sure why adding the print produces the warning, apparently the compiler then believes it shouldn't be a partial but a total function or something. Anyways a better way of writing that function would have been  `{ case Input(id, InnerA(name)) => Output(id, InnerA(name)) }`

Comment: That's not a partialfunction definition. You just define a regular function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this partial function pf doesn't blow up with a MatchError when inner is not InnerA

If you call it directly with such an argument

```
pf(Input("a", InnerB("b", 0)))
```

you *do* get a `MatchError`; but the whole point of `PartialFunction` is to provide additional information in `isDefinedAt`, and `collect` uses it by not calling `pf` where `isDefinedAt` returns `false`.

> Is this quirk documented somewhere?

See paragraph [6.23.1 Translation](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#translation) of specification:

> > When a `PartialFunction` is required, an additional member `isDefinedAt` is synthesized, which simply returns `true`. However, if the function literal has the shape `x => x match { … }`, then `isDefinedAt` is derived from the pattern match in the following way: each case from the match expression evaluates to `true`, and if there is no default case, a default case is added that evaluates to `false`.

So for your second version `isDefinedAt` is always `true`; the first one doesn't *exactly* fit `x => x match...`, but apparently it's supported too. Now the usual way to define a `PartialFunction` is like Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez's comment says

```
{ case Input(id, InnerA(name)) => Output(id, InnerA(name)) }
```

but it simply gets translated into

```
x => x match { case Input(id, InnerA(name)) => Output(id, InnerA(name)) }
```

Comment: _if the function literal has the shape `x => x match { … }`, then `isDefinedAt` is derived from the pattern match_

That's what I was looking for, thank you. I find surprising that the synthetic `isDefined` completely changes between the two examples, but it is what it is :)

Answer (score 4):

What is happening is that, in the first case, the compiler is "removing" the `input` match from and using `input.inner`.

When I run `scalac -Xprint:typer Test.scala`, the first code turns into:

```scala
final override def applyOrElse[A1 <: Input, B1 >: Output](input: A1, default: A1 => B1): B1 = (input.inner: Inner @unchecked) match {
  case (innerA @ (_: InnerA)) => {
    val id: String = (input: A1 @unchecked) match {
      case (id: String, inner: Inner): Input((id @ _), _) => id
    };
    Output.apply(id, innerA)
  }
  case (defaultCase$ @ _) => default.apply(input)
};

final def isDefinedAt(input: Input): Boolean = (input.inner: Inner @unchecked) match {
  case (innerA @ (_: InnerA)) => true
  case (defaultCase$ @ _) => false
}
```

Which means that your function will behave like a `PartialFunction[Inner, Output]`, so the compiler knows that it doesn't need to warn you that your match is not exhaustive.

On the other hand, when you see the results for the method with the print instruction, you get:

```scala
final override def applyOrElse[A1 <: Input, B1 >: Output](input: A1, default: A1 => B1): B1 = ((input.asInstanceOf[Input]: Input): Input @unchecked) match {
  case (defaultCase$ @ _) => {
    scala.Predef.println("xxx");
    input.inner match {
      case (innerA @ (_: InnerA)) => {
        val id: String = (input: A1 @unchecked) match {
          case (id: String, inner: Inner): Input((id @ _), _) => id
        };
        Output.apply(id, innerA)
      }
    }
  }
  case (defaultCase$ @ _) => default.apply(input)
};
final def isDefinedAt(input: Input): Boolean = ((input.asInstanceOf[Input]: Input): Input @unchecked) match {
  case (defaultCase$ @ _) => true
  case (defaultCase$ @ _) => false
}
```

In this case, you're creating a `PartialFunction[Input, Output]` that is defined for all intervals of Input, and this is fine. But when the compiler checks the inner `input.inner match`, it warns you that this match - not the first one - is not exhaustive.